# How to get full address of current request in Kohana?

Tags: kohana

If I'm on page `https://www.example.com/test?page=123` how can I get this FULL PATH (proto + host + URI + query ) with Kohana?

I've tried `Request::uri()`, `Request::url()`: they don't give me full address string. Only URI part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [URL helper](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/URL) which contains methods which will achieve your goal...

```
URL::base();
```

That should work for the host, if you tack it onto the front of your `Request::uri()`. If you need the `http://` on the front, add `true` as the first parameter. Then there's...

```
URL::query();
```

which you can use to get the query string (and add additional parameters if necessary).

So something like...

```
$current_url = URL::base(true).Request::uri().URL::query();
```

should produce the full URL.

Comment: Correct answer depends on Kohana version

Comment: I was assuming >3 because of the OP's use of Request::uri() which replaced url::current() in prior versions.

Comment: `Request::current()->url().URL::query()` or `$this->request->url().URL::query()`

Comment: `Request::current()->url().URL::query()` returns only `URI` + `query`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Kohana 3.3.2 and this works for me:

```
$current_url = URL::site(Request::detect_uri(), TRUE) . URL::query();
```